# Error: message sent to deallocated instance in

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging

This question derives from a previous question I asked. I had some help with debugging, but now I have this error appearing in the console of Xcode:

```
[CFURL absoluteURL]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x949dde0
```

I have already done a search through all the files for an instance of `absoluteURL` but it just seems to lead me to some ASIHttp files, as I have been using that lib.

I am using a Twitter Auth code example, which comes with some OAuth libraries, and I have a feeling that there may be a problem with the following code:

```
NSString * authorizationHeader = OAuthorizationHeader([NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"],
                                                     method,
                                                     bodyData,
                                                     [GSTwitterSignedRequest consumerKey],
                                                     [GSTwitterSignedRequest consumerSecret],
                                                     _authToken,
                                                     _authTokenSecret);
```

I just don't fully understand how to track this down. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My experience with "message sent to deallocated instance" is that it's a red herring -- the problem may lie somewhere else.

Comment: *Message sent to deallocated instance* is not a red herring, it is the root of the problem.  The underlying issue is that something -- in this case, a CFURL -- is being released prematurely.

Comment: I have no idea where that might be, it's so frustrating. I wish the messages were more helpful. Does anybody know of an easy way to track down in the actual code where the root of the problem lies?

Comment: Look at all the places where you create an NSURL object, and see if you might be over-releasing one somewhere.  (Keep in mind that some library routine may be doing the absoluteURL call.)

Comment: @bbum, I think sending absoluteURL isn't the root of the problem, but  an indication that something is being sent to a released object. Any message sent to a deallocated instance will result in the error -- so searching for absoluteURL is a small distraction, aka a red herring.

Comment: @bbum, misread, I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable zombies and run your app under the Allocations instrument in Instruments with Zombies enabled.  Also turn on "track reference counts" and "only track live allocations" (approximations of names -- don't have it in front of me;  two checkboxes in the Allocations Instrument).

When the app hits the *message sent to deallocated instance* error, you should be able to see all of the retains/releases on that object and, more importantly, exactly where it was allocated.

Somewhere, there is an URL being prematurely released or over-released.

---

See "To Find Zombies" in the [Instruments documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html).

Comment: Ahh cool, okay I'll give this a shot and see if it helps me track it down.

Comment: As soon as I enable AUtomatic Reference Counting, ASIHTTP comes up with so many errors. I can't build the project with this enabled.

Comment: Not ARC -- but the reference count tracker in Instruments.   In the long running, converting to ARC is a good idea (note that you can convert just your source files to ARC and leave ASIHTTP non-ARC, but that is unrelated to this crash).  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html